# Derivation involving finite unitary transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Hi I just want to confirm a short derivation involving a particular finite unitary transformation which is important in QM. My working is as follows:

Given the finite unitary transformation defined by 
$$
\hat{U_{\tau}}(\hat{H}) = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\left(\hat{I} + \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\tau}{N}\hat{H}\right)^{N} = e^{\tfrac{i}{\hbar}\tau \hat{H}}.
\tag{01}
$$
 Using the Schrodinger equation in the first equation and the Taylor expansion in the second we get: 
$$
\left(\hat{I} + \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\tau}{N}\hat{H}\right)|\psi(t) \rangle = |\psi(t) \rangle - \frac{\tau}{N}\frac{\partial |\psi(t) \rangle}{\partial t} \approx \bigg| \psi \left(t-\frac{\tau}{N}\right) \Big\rangle.
\tag{02}
$$
 Hence we have 
$$
\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\left(\hat{I} + \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\tau}{N}\hat{H}\right)^{N}|\psi(t) \rangle = | \psi(t-\tau) \rangle.
\tag{03}
$$ 
Therefore it follows that 
$$
\hat{U_{\tau}}(\hat{H})|\psi(t) \rangle=\left[ \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\left(\hat{I} + \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\tau}{N}\hat{H}\right)^{N}\right]|\psi(t) \rangle =  e^{\tfrac{i}{\hbar}\tau \hat{H}} | \psi(t) \rangle =  \psi(t-\tau) \rangle.
\tag{04}
$$

Comment: It seems to be OK. As the momentum operator is the generator of displacements in space .....
\begin{align}
& \mathbf{p}    =-i\hbar \boldsymbol{\nabla}\\
& U_{\mathbf{x}}\left(\boldsymbol{\rho}\right)\psi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)  = e^{-i \tfrac{\rho \boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{p}}{\hbar}}\psi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)=\psi\left(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\rho}\right)
\tag{01}
\end{align}

Comment: ..... so the Hamiltonian is the generator of displacements in time
\begin{align}
& H  =i\hbar \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\\
& U_{t}\left(\tau \right)\psi\left( t \right) = e^{i \tfrac{\tau\cdot H}{\hbar}}\psi\left (t \right)=\psi \left(t-\tau\right)
\tag{02}
\end{align}